# How to change Background color of Table row if the value of column is same?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to set same and different background color of Table rows where the column value matches previous or next row of same for same column.

For example, Check the below table.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead class="table-light fw-semibold">
    <tr class="align-middle">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Profession</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="align-middle">
        <td>
            John
        </td>
        <td>
            25
        </td>
        <td>
            Architect
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="align-middle">
        <td>
            John
        </td>
        <td>
            35
        </td>
        <td>
            Teacher
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="align-middle">
        <td>
            Jerry
        </td>
        <td>
            30
        </td>
        <td>
            Broker
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In the above table. The name column of the first row matches name of 2nd(next) row. So I want to set a different background color for both the matched rows.

How can I do that using JS/jQuery?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Iterate over the rows of the table, compare the relevant cell with the cell of the previous/next table row. If the content matches change the color of the table row (e.g. add a CSS class)

Comment: Actually I have got some idea about if the cell value matches any condition like value less or greater than something, or the cell matches any exact string, but not getting any idea how can I compare it with next or previous row. Searched a lot in stack overflow, but not getting exactly same solution.

Comment: _"Iterate over the rows..."_ - You either have an index or you can get the previous/next row with some DOM traversal.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to iterate the rows. I wasn't sure which columns you wanted to compare with the previous row, so I compared all columns and if any match, I mark those rows with a background.

```js
var previous_values = new Array(100)
var previous_row = null;
document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr").forEach(function(row) {
  var i = 0;
  var found = false;
  row.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(function(td) {
    var value = td.innerText;
    if (value == previous_values[i]) {
      found = true;
    }
    previous_values[i] = value;
    i++;
  })
  if (found) {
    row.classList.add("bg-primary");
    if (previous_row) {
      previous_row.classList.add("bg-primary");
    }
  }
  previous_row = row;

})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead class="table-light fw-semibold">
    <tr class="align-middle">
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Profession</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="align-middle">
      <td>
        John
      </td>
      <td>
        25
      </td>
      <td>
        Architect
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="align-middle">
      <td>
        John
      </td>
      <td>
        35
      </td>
      <td>
        Teacher
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="align-middle">
      <td>
        Jerry
      </td>
      <td>
        30
      </td>
      <td>
        Broker
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```